# MySql pivot for unknown number of column headers

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot, dynamic-pivot

I have a MySql query which I would like to pivot dynamically, with Company names as column headers and the company financial fields as row headers.

Currently I have this:

```
SELECT Company, TotalRevenue, Overhead, TotalJobCosts, GrossProfit 
FROM comp_financials
```

which gives me this:

| Company | TotalRevenue | Overhead | TotalJobCosts | GrossProfit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Chicago's Best Construction | 2098001 | 363750 | 1424420 | 673581 |
| Jones Construction | 4509458 | 1067008 | 2876568 | 1632890 |

and I wish to get something like this:

|  | Chicago's Best Construction | Jones Construction |
| --- | --- | --- |
| TotalRevenue | 2098001 | 4509458 |
| Overhead | 363750 | 1067008 |
| TotalJobCosts | 1424420 | 2876568 |
| GrossProfit | 673581 | 1632890 |

with an unknown number of companies and their values (but generally less than 20).

I've gotten this far to display the company names as column headers dynamically, but can't get how to display the row values (row headers are not necessary).

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 32000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN Company = ''',
               Company,
               ''' THEN Company ELSE NULL END) AS ',
               CONCAT('`', Company, '`')
               )) INTO @sql
FROM comp_financials;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT ', @sql, ' 
                   FROM comp_financials');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Comment: The values for `Jones Construction` in the expected output are different than the first query result.

Comment: @FaNo_FN - this is fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First thing to do is turning columns into rows. Method is simple; just need to use `UNION ALL`. Something like this:

```
SELECT 1 as r,company, "TotalRevenue" val, TotalRevenue totals FROM comp_financials UNION ALL
SELECT 2, company, "Overhead", Overhead FROM comp_financials UNION ALL
SELECT 3, company, "TotalJobCosts", TotalJobCosts FROM comp_financials UNION ALL
SELECT 4, company, "GrossProfit", GrossProfit FROM comp_financials
```

I've added numbering (`.. as r`) for later use in `ORDER BY`. `val` values corresponds to the column name that I'm retrieving data from. This query will return data like the following:

| r | company | val | totals |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Jones Construction | TotalRevenue | 4509458 |
| 1 | Chicago's Best Construction | TotalRevenue | 2098001 |
| 2 | Jones Construction | Overhead | 1067008 |
| 2 | Chicago's Best Construction | Overhead | 363750 |
| 3 | Jones Construction | TotalJobCosts | 2876568 |
| 3 | Chicago's Best Construction | TotalJobCosts | 1424420 |
| 4 | Jones Construction | GrossProfit | 1632890 |
| 4 | Chicago's Best Construction | GrossProfit | 673581 |

The query above I make as a derived query for the original query you were doing. So the end result looks like this:

```
SELECT r,val,
       MAX(CASE WHEN company="Jones construction" THEN totals END) AS "Jones construction",
       MAX(CASE WHEN company="Chicago's Best Construction" THEN totals END) AS "Chicago's Best Construction"
FROM
(SELECT 1 as r,company, "TotalRevenue" val, TotalRevenue totals FROM comp_financials UNION ALL
SELECT 2, company, "Overhead", Overhead FROM comp_financials UNION ALL
SELECT 3, company, "TotalJobCosts", TotalJobCosts FROM comp_financials UNION ALL
SELECT 4, company, "GrossProfit", GrossProfit FROM comp_financials) B
GROUP BY r,val
ORDER BY r ASC
```

Additionally, I've grouped by `r` and `val` then order it by `r`. This query returns data like the following:

| r | val | Jones construction | Chicago's Best Construction |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | TotalRevenue | 4509458 | 2098001 |
| 2 | Overhead | 1067008 | 363750 |
| 3 | TotalJobCosts | 2876568 | 1424420 |
| 4 | GrossProfit | 1632890 | 673581 |

Adding this to your prepared statement:

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 32000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
        CONCAT('MAX(CASE WHEN Company = "',
               Company,
               '" THEN totals ELSE NULL END) AS ',
               CONCAT('"', Company, '"')
               )) INTO @sql
FROM comp_financials;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT r,val, ', @sql, '
   FROM
(SELECT 1 as r,company, "TotalRevenue" val, TotalRevenue totals FROM comp_financials UNION ALL
SELECT 2, company, "Overhead", Overhead FROM comp_financials UNION ALL
SELECT 3, company, "TotalJobCosts", TotalJobCosts FROM comp_financials UNION ALL
SELECT 4, company, "GrossProfit", GrossProfit FROM comp_financials) B
GROUP BY r,val
ORDER BY r ASC');
select @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Here's a demo fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=678de8991e21ccd90d2195d3d5eca0a7

P/S: Next time, please don't post image for data tables or anything (codes) that we could copy and paste. Fortunately this only have a couple of data rows so it's easier to re-create but not many are willing to help if they see photos instead.

Comment: Yes, this does the trick.  And I replaced the table images with actual tables - good heads-up.  Amazing that MySql makes you jump through so many hoops to Pivot compared to other SQL flavors.